# "We receive..." meaning

Tags: meaning

Recently I wrote a science article. I sent it to a website and they responded with:

> We receive the paper [...]

What does "receive" mean here? I can't ask them what did they mean. They've read but haven't accepted yet or they accepted the paper?

Comment: It should be *received.*  In fact, to be precise, *have received...* If they are not too informal!

Comment: It means your article has arrived, nothing more unless the reply says so.

Comment: can't believe. You sent them an English paper, and didn't know "receive"...

Comment: @above: They use "receive", not "received". That's why I have a little confusing

Answer (score 1):

It should be "We have received the paper"

This is nothing more than a courtesy to let you know that the paper has arrived at their office, and not been lost in the post. It doesn't mean that it has been accepted. It doesn't even mean that it has been read, or even that an editor has been assigned to read it.

The process of accepting a paper can be a slow one, especially if a peer review is required or if modifications need to be made.